# How to add layers into keras functional object (e.g InceptionResNetV2)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model, functional-programming, layer

I am trying to add layers into the InceptionResNetV2 (or any other pretrained network that can be imported via tf.keras.applications). I do know that I can add the object to a sequential model or functional model. However, when I do that, I won't be able to **access individual outputs** from the layers to use them in **Grad-CAM or similar applications**.

I am using the following model structure right now. It works, it can be trained. However, it does NOT allow me to access output of the last convolutional layer of InceptionResNetV2 in regards to a specific input and specific output.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
InceptionResNetV2 = tf.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2.InceptionResNetV2

def get_base():
    conv_base = InceptionResNetV2(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    conv_base.trainable = False
    return(conv_base)


def get_model():
    base = get_base()

    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
    x = base(inputs, training=False)
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(512, "relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
    x = layers.Dense(256, "relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
    dims = layers.Dense(2, name="Valence_Arousal")(x)
    expression = layers.Dense(2, name="Emotion_Category")(x)


    model = models.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[expression, dims])
    return(model)

print(get_model().summary())
```

Comment: Why you can't access to last conv layer? `get_model().layers[1].layers[...]` should work.

Comment: @Frightera, I can not access the output of a certain layer in regards to a certain input. If I were using a sequential model like VGG, I would be adding layers into a new sequential model with a for loop but with huge models it is not possible unless I extract every single layer, replicate every single interaction and that is only theoretically possible.

Comment: So you want every layer to be visible in model summary then? Is it necessary to get base model from a function or can you define it in `get_model()`?

Comment: @Frightera Yes, I am trying to get every layer to be visible in model summary. Getting base model can be done within anything. I can simply define it in get_model or even create a class if necessary. As long as it creates results, I can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding the nested models are difficult after they're created. Passing `input_tensor` argument to the pretrained model gives the expected results.

```
def get_model():

    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
    
    conv_base = InceptionResNetV2(weights=None, include_top=False, input_tensor = inputs)
    conv_base.trainable = False
    
    x = layers.Flatten()(conv_base.output)
    x = layers.Dense(512, "relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
    x = layers.Dense(256, "relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
    
    dims = layers.Dense(2, name="Valence_Arousal")(x)
    expression = layers.Dense(2, name="Emotion_Category")(x)


    model = models.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[expression, dims])
    return(model)
```

Model summary:

```
input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 224, 224, 3  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
conv2d (Conv2D)                (None, 111, 111, 32  864         ['input_1[0][0]']                
                                )  
...
```

Comment: Does this somehow work also  for Sequential model?

Comment: I guess this was a special case for pretrained models which use functional API under the hood, I am not sure if it would work.